# How to create a .xapk file? Can I make it from a .apk and a .obb file?

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, build, export, apk-expansion-files

When I googled this question on the Internet, there was none about how to create instead of install. I saw they were just zip files but I do not really know if I can just put everything into a zip and change its file extension to .xapk and it is done. So my question is: Can I simply zip a .apk and a .obb files (build from Unity) to make a .xapk file? Or I need to arrange it with some specific folder structure? Or I can only make it from an Android project in Android Studio?

Answer (score 3):

It seems the answer is NO. It needs an "manifest.json" file, as detailed in Caleb Fenton's blog.

http://calebfenton.github.io/2016/02/28/decompiling-xapk-files/

The question of how to generate the file automatically still eludes me. I haven't been able to find a "xapk creator" or something.